# How to apply changes of a specific file of the other git repository to my own repo

Tags: git, version-control, diff, patch

There are two repositories `/a/.git` and `/b/.git` and they both have a file called `c.txt`. This file was the same between them before but now `c.txt` was modified in repo `a`. How can I extract this change and apply it to repo `b` without manually copy-paste? The modification of `c.txt` was committed with other changes in repo `a` but I only want the patch of the specific `c.txt`.

P.S. and if possible, I would like to preserve the original author when committing this change to repo `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below steps to make the version of `c.txt` from `repoA` (`/a/.git`) to repoB (`/b/.git`):

```
# In local repoB /b/.git
git remote add -f a /a/.git
gitk --all   #To find the commit id where remotes/a/master point to (assume the new version of c.txt in master branch)
git cherry-pick <commit id you find in above step> -X theirs
```

Now the new version of `c.txt` in `/b/.git` with keeping the original author.

Comment: Thanks. This should work but the modification of some other files (which I don't want to commit) will also be committed to my repoB. I should use `git cherry-pick xxx -n` and accept/reject changes of the file and commit it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a new remote with repo-a-url (say, repob) in repo-b. Then *checkout* the file to repo-b any specific branch (say, master).

Go into `repo-b` then try the following commands:

```
$ git remote add repoa <repo-a-url>     # add a new remote repoa = repo-a-url
$ git fetch repoa                       # sync with repoa

$ git checkout repoa/master c.txt       # checkout the file to 'repoa' 'master' branch

$ git log --numstat --oneline c.txt     # show the change lists of c.txt file
```

Comment: Thanks. This one should also work but it won't work if I modify the other part of the file (it is my fault not to mention it). Cherry-pick should do better than this.